# Native image using Graal, Gradle and the Gluon Client doesn't load my main FXML [Windows]

Tags: gradle, javafx, gluon

This is related to my first question, but since I got further the issue changed quite a bit. I'm not able to find information regarding this (seemingly simple issue) on native images and Windows.

**Situation**: IntelliJ runs my app, creating an executable Jar works as well and runs.

**Problem**: I get a loadexception on my main FXML for native images. It is not a "location not set" error, so I don't think it's a runtime classpath issue.

**My thinking**: Since the issue with my Jar was the runtime classpath, might this still be the case for the native image? If so, how do I set that in the gluonClient{} path?

**Solution**: With the help of @JoséPereda, the issue was an incomplete reflectionList. Adding the stacktrace to my catch block showed my the "classes not found" I still had to add. My confusion comes from the fact this all isn't an issue in the jar and IntelliJ. I've got some reading up to do. :)

**Error**:

```
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][INFO] ==================== RUN TASK ====================
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] PB Command for run until end: C:\Users\vince\Documents\Company\Company-APP\Programming\Java\Projects\AstroPixelProcessor-javafx\build\client\x86_64-windows\AstroPixelProcessor-javafx.exe
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] Start process run until end...
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] There was a problem loading the main view fxml; javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] views/MainView.fxml
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] 
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] Exception in Application start method
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] Something went wrong with launching the JavaFX runtime.
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.astropixelprocessor.APP.start(APP.java:41)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:101)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     ... 3 more
[Fri Oct 02 19:34:12 CEST 2020][FINE] Result for run until end: 0
```

**Build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'distribution'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin' version '0.1.31'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation('junit:junit:4.13')
}

group 'com.ariesproductions'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 11
mainClassName = 'com.astropixelprocessor.Main'

javafx {
    version = '15'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

gluonClient {
    reflectionList = ["com.astropixelprocessor.APP"]
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.astropixelprocessor.Main'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

**This is the class concerned**:

```
public class APP extends Application {

    private static final String mainViewTitle = "my app";
    private static final String mainViewPath = "/views/MainView.fxml";
    private static final String themePath = "/dark-theme.css";

    private Stage primaryStage;

    public APP() {}

    public void show(){
        launch();
    }

    // JavaFX start method, application entry point
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        FXMLLoader primarySceneViewLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(mainViewPath));

        Parent primarySceneRootNode = null;

        try {
            primarySceneRootNode = primarySceneViewLoader.load();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem loading the main view fxml; " + e.toString());
        }

        assert primarySceneRootNode != null;
        primarySceneRootNode.getStylesheets().add(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource(themePath)));

        primaryStage.setTitle(mainViewTitle);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(primarySceneRootNode));

        try {
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.err.println("The primary stage show method is called on a thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Catch the application close event and display a quit stage
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent ->

        {
            // Stop the system from acting on this event
            windowEvent.consume();
            SimpleAlertViewController.showQuitStage();
        });
    }
}
```

**Part of my main view fxml**:

```
<VBox fx:id="mainWindow" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.astropixelprocessor.controllers.MainViewController">
    <MenuBar prefWidth="1280.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open…" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Recent" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Revert" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preferences…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem fx:id="quitMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#menuHandler" text="Quit">
            <accelerator>
               <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="Q" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="DOWN" />
            </accelerator></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

**Extra stacktrace on the loadexception**:

```
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] views/MainView.fxml
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] 
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2629)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2867)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2711)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2680)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2546)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2470)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2439)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.astropixelprocessor.APP.start(APP.java:35)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:101)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.ComboBox
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.ClassForNameSupport.forName(ClassForNameSupport.java:60)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:233)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2935)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2924)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2865)
[Sat Oct 03 13:50:21 CEST 2020][FINE] [SUB]     ... 18 more
```

Comment: @JoséPereda I posted the class code as well above. That class is in fact in the reflectionlist as can be seen in my build.gradle configuration.

Comment: Thx, but you are still missing the controller classes from `fx:controller` in your FXML files. I see that the exception mentions MainView.

Comment: @JoséPereda Mm, so I pasted part of that MainView FXML, but do you mean that the controller for a FXML is also a reflective class? Sorry, I'm quite new to reflection and I thought a class is reflective if it incorporates reflection methods like (getClass()) etc.

Comment: See https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/#_hellofxml_sample, all classes and methods found in an FXML file are invoked by the FXMLLoader via reflection

Comment: @JoséPereda Right, ok I'll read into that better, thanks a lot. I did now try to add it to the reflectionlist but unfortunately the error remains the same.

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block, to see the full exception. Most likely you have some method in your FXML that needs to be included in the reflection list or file (https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/#_jni_and_reflection).

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks so much for your help and patience! I indeed get more information now and have added the cause above at the end of the post. It is another "class not found" issue. Which is a bit weird to me as the rest seems to work.

Comment: Then you should be able to read the CNFEs in that trace, and add the referred classes to the reflection list. It will require some iterations...

Comment: @JoséPereda: Allright, that is amazing, as you probably can tell I'm fairly new to all of this, but I indeed got further with some iterations and now it launches! I was under the impression that the plugin already took care of the javafx classes. But that would be a bit too easy and less fun. ;) Thank you so much!

Comment: The plugin takes care of many JavaFX classes, but not all. See [note](reflectionList). You can check `target/client/$arch-$os/gvm/reflectionconfig-$arch-$os.json` for the currently supported classes and methods. Your classes in the reflectionList are added to that file.

Comment: I noticed that indeed, thanks yet again. learning fast. :)

Comment: Use of the tracing agent https://medium.com/graalvm/introducing-the-tracing-agent-simplifying-graalvm-native-image-configuration-c3b56c486271 would have made all this a lesser pain :-(

Comment: @mipa Yes, I just found that by an answer on a question I had on Github. That indeed takes all the manual work out of the equation. I sometimes do like more manual approaches, just to learn more about the background. But am using the agent now.